# Have multiple method=RequestMethod.POST in controller and how to call each of them?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, parameters

In my spring controller, I have three functions

```
@Controller
public class Controll {

    @RequestMapping(value="/signup",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String signup(@ModelAttribute("signuper") Signuper signuper, ModelMap model){

        if(signuper.getSignupFName()!=null){  
            //dosomething
            return "emailForm";              
        }
      
        //dosomething
        return "signupForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/signup",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String signup(@Valid Signuper signuper,BindingResult result, ModelMap model,
        RedirectAttributes attributes)
    {
        //dosomething
        attributes.addFlashAttribute("signuper",signuper);
        return "redirect:signup";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/signup",method=RequestMethod.POST, params = "email")
    public String signupE(@Valid EmailVerify emailVerify,BindingResult result,ModelMap model) {
        //dosomething
        return "signupSuccess";
    }
}
```

The user goes to /signup in the web browser.
Method(signup with method = GET) gets called.
User fills out "signupForm" and the info goes to Method(signup with method = POST).
Method(signup with method = POST) does validation and if everything is good, it redirects back to Method(signup with method = GET) with Signuper info. Becuase signuper.getSignupFName() will not be null now, user will have to fill "emailForm".

How do I go to Method(signupE with method = POST)?

MAIN QUESTIONS TO ANSWER (everything else was background info, but pls read it) :

1. How do you create a param in a method so that when it can pick which method = POST Method it can call?
2. How to have multiple method=RequestMethod.POST in controller and how to call each of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. How do you create a param in a method so that when it can pick which method = POST Method it can call?**

I suppose you want to call the method signupE once the user fills the "emailForm". So in the "emailForm", the form "action" URL would have to be attached with a request parameter. How you do that depends on what server side tech you have used for generating the HTML pages. It can be JSP/Thymeleaf etc. If you need help with that, specify which one you're using.

I can see that you've specified **params = "email"** in the RequestMapping, but you haven't specified any @RequestParam("email") in the method arguments. It should be specified like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/signup",method=RequestMethod.POST, params = "email")
   public String signupE(@RequestParam("email") String email, @Valid EmailVerify emailVerify,BindingResult result,ModelMap model) {
       //dosomething
       return "signupSuccess";
   }
```

**2. How to have multiple method=RequestMethod.POST in controller and how to call each of them?**

One of the ways to do that is by differentiating them on the basis of request parameters, using the "params" attribute. Since you've already used that, I don't think I should explain how that works.